# Hapi.js, CouchDB and trouble handling AuthSession token

Tags: session, authentication, cookies, couchdb, hapi.js

I'm having a problem with the current setup of mine. I'm using Hapi.js and CouchDB. I'm trying to use CouchDB cookie authentication.

I'm getting the AuthSession token from CouchDB by querying /_session with username and password. So that is fine.

The problem is that I don't know what to do with the AuthSession token. Where to store it? I've read that I could store it in Redis for example. But then how? In what format?

Let's say I save user's ID and AuthSession token into Redis. Then let's say there are 5 users logged in at the same time and therefore there are 5 tokens in Redis. How do I know which token to get from Redis for each request made by the users?

Answer (score 0):

The way cookie authentication works in CouchDB is like this:

1. `POST` to `/_session` with credentials that match users in the `/_users` db.
2. The response contains an instruction for the browser to set the AuthSession cookie.
3. From that point, all further requests (including ajax) to that domain are made with the cookie.

If you're needing to store the AuthSession cookie somewhere between the browser and CouchDB, it might be easier to still let the browser set the cookie, and then just pass it to CouchDB when the request comes in.

Comment: Hmm.. User sends a log in form with credentials and then the server side (Hapi) handles the /_session request to the database (CouchDB). So the response is given to the server and not to the client. But how to actually pass the cookie to the client and from client to the database?

Comment: I don't know much about hapi.js. sorry. A quick search turns up this tutorial about getting and setting cookies between the browser and the hapi.js application. http://hapijs.com/tutorials/cookies . Getting and settings cookies between hapi.js and couch depends on what you're using to make those network requests in your hapi app.